# India Street Ambience

Tags: street, ambience

I'm right now working on a film with an intro much like The Hurt Locker but this film is in India. Estab shots on slums and poverty-stricken streets.

I really like the intro to The Hurt Locker with the megaphone speech and the gritty ambiences.

Has anyone been to India? Do you know what a street such as this one would have included sound-wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what sort of urban setting the slum is in. Hard carts are a rare sight these days and a lot of the slums even have televisions. You could layer these sounds:

- Crows (lots of them)
- Indian Koyal (bird)
- Pigeons (wing flap/cooeing depending on location)
- Chickens
- Distant television
- Dogs
- kids playing
- Two wheelers
- three wheeler auto rickshaws
- Metal utensils (maybe something cooking on a kerosene stove)
- Radio
- Hand washing clothes
- Faucet/water running
- Traffic ambiance (trucks, motorcycles, cars..make sure there are enough horns heard)

Email me (nothingtokeep[at]gmail[dot]com), I probably could share a few sounds with you.

Comment: that's a pretty cool sound diary entry! nice one!

Comment: Yeah @ntkeep covered pretty much everything you hear there. I'm visiting right now 3 days before I leave, I also don't mind giving away some of the stuff I recorded here, they probably won't be as good as his but I got a few rickshaw recordings and those three wheeler trucks.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a busy market street. A lot of traffic, small cars and mopeds, rickshaws both pulled by motor bike or horses, lots of people.

Answer (score 3):

Hello.

I have been in India last month and record a lot of sounds.
You can ear some examples on my blog :
www.faunethic.org

Maybe i can share some sounds too.

Bye.

Comment: nice recordings!

Answer (score 3):

Indian musical instruments

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the street vendors!  Indian street vendors tend to be pretty vocal.

Answer (score 1):

A search on youtube shows that a street market's ambience includes all the elements that the rest of the guys have indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Harmonium in the background. We had a lot of street vendor stuff (check your region/language). There are horns constantly and we found that we had take a heap out because they would drive the audience nuts. Agree with the crows as well - we had an interior dialogue where a crow got into the building, it took forever to edit it out. I went back and watched Slumdog Millionaire. Have a look at The Waiting City